# Get string before a whitespace on a Pandas series in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am preparing data for plotting but im currently encountering issues on applying functions on dataframes in Pandas

This is my dataframe:

[image]

What I need to do is to get only the date from the timestamp. So in the current dataframe, the expected result should look like this:

```
             timestamp    action
0           2020-03-03 pagevisit
1           2020-03-03 pagevisit
2           2020-03-03 pagevisit
3           2020-03-03 pagevisit
4           2020-03-03 pagevisit
```

I have around 100,000 records that I need to clean and get only the date. I tried

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

And it returns error

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'
```

--
I also tried

```
df['timestamp'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['timestamp'].split(' ')[0])
```

But it returns

```
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'timestamp'
```

I feel that this is a fairly easy task but I have already checked for the past hour but still can't get it. My pandas ver is 1.0.1 so I honestly do not know the cause and I am already desperate. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error, it seems that the column timestamp have type of `pd.Timestamp`

(check documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)

If you just want to get the date as string you can do as follow

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: str(x.date()))
```

(or you can just use `x.date()` to get the `datetime.date` type )

Comment: Makes sense that the column is not a object but a datetime.
`timestamp    datetime64[ns, Asia/Tokyo]
action                           object
dtype: object`

All this time I thought its an object. It explains why I can't manipulate it as such.

Thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.date()`

**Ex:**

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].date()
```

**Demo:**

```
print(pd.Timestamp('2020-03-03 12:13:56+09:00').date())
# -->2020-03-03
```

Comment: Using the same dataframe, I tried your code and it returned this error
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'`